# Single Integrals and a function defined on $R^3$

Tags: calculus

Let's say i had a function $f:R^3 \to R$. Would it be possible to some how form the integral $\int f(x,y,z)dx$?

Comment: You can always treat $y$ and $z$ as constants as long as they have no dependence on $x$.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg Thank you for your response. Could you point me to a resource where  a mathematics undergraduate who hasn't taken real analysis yet can understand more about what you can do with  integrals and derivatives. I always feel like there is too much intuition used in my classes.

Comment: Any Calculus textbook will do. If you're more interested in applications than simply calculus-for-the-sake-of-it then I'd go with Calculus: Early Transcendentals by Stewart. Also, if you're interested in real analysis I'd take a look at SUMS Real Analysis by Howie (which I found really useful).